# Speed up sampling of kernel estimate

Tags: python, numpy, performance, montecarlo

Here's a `MWE` of a much larger code I'm using. Basically, it performs a Monte Carlo integration over a KDE ([kernel density estimate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html)) for all values located below a certain threshold (the integration method was suggested over at this question BTW: [Integrate 2D kernel density estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822282/integrate-2d-kernel-density-estimate?rq=1)).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import time

# Generate some random two-dimensional data:
def measure(n):
    "Measurement model, return two coupled measurements."
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2

# Get data.
m1, m2 = measure(20000)
# Define limits.
xmin = m1.min()
xmax = m1.max()
ymin = m2.min()
ymax = m2.max()

# Perform a kernel density estimate on the data.
x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)

# Define point below which to integrate the kernel.
x1, y1 = 0.5, 0.5

# Get kernel value for this point.
tik = time.time()
iso = kernel((x1,y1))
print 'iso: ', time.time()-tik

# Sample from KDE distribution (Monte Carlo process).
tik = time.time()
sample = kernel.resample(size=1000)
print 'resample: ', time.time()-tik

# Filter the sample leaving only values for which
# the kernel evaluates to less than what it does for
# the (x1, y1) point defined above.
tik = time.time()
insample = kernel(sample) < iso
print 'filter/sample: ', time.time()-tik

# Integrate for all values below iso.
tik = time.time()
integral = insample.sum() / float(insample.shape[0])
print 'integral: ', time.time()-tik
```

The output looks something like this:

```
iso:  0.00259208679199
resample:  0.000817060470581
filter/sample:  2.10829401016
integral:  4.2200088501e-05
```

which clearly means that the *filter/sample* call is consuming almost all of the time the code uses to run. I have to run this block of code iteratively several thousand times so it can get pretty time consuming.

Is there any way to speed up the filtering/sampling process?

---

### Add

Here's a slightly more realistic `MWE` of my actual code with Ophion's multi-threading solution written into it:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from multiprocessing import Pool

def kde_integration(m_list):

    m1, m2 = [], []
    for item in m_list:
        # Color data.
        m1.append(item[0])
        # Magnitude data.
        m2.append(item[1])

    # Define limits.
    xmin, xmax = min(m1), max(m1)
    ymin, ymax = min(m2), max(m2)

    # Perform a kernel density estimate on the data:
    x, y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:100j, ymin:ymax:100j]
    values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
    kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)

    out_list = []

    for point in m_list:

        # Compute the point below which to integrate.
        iso = kernel((point[0], point[1]))

        # Sample KDE distribution
        sample = kernel.resample(size=1000)

        #Create definition.
        def calc_kernel(samp):
            return kernel(samp)

        #Choose number of cores and split input array.
        cores = 4
        torun = np.array_split(sample, cores, axis=1)

        #Calculate
        pool = Pool(processes=cores)
        results = pool.map(calc_kernel, torun)

        #Reintegrate and calculate results
        insample_mp = np.concatenate(results) < iso

        # Integrate for all values below iso.
        integral = insample_mp.sum() / float(insample_mp.shape[0])

        out_list.append(integral)

    return out_list


# Generate some random two-dimensional data:
def measure(n):
    "Measurement model, return two coupled measurements."
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2

# Create list to pass.
m_list = []
for i in range(60):
    m1, m2 = measure(5)
    m_list.append(m1.tolist())
    m_list.append(m2.tolist())

# Call KDE integration function.
print 'Integral result: ', kde_integration(m_list)
```

The solution presented by *Ophion* works great on the original code I presented, but fails with the following error in this version:

```
Integral result: Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 319, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

I tried moving the `calc_kernel` function around since one of the answers in this question [Multiprocessing: How to use Pool.map on a function defined in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288595/multiprocessing-using-pool-map-on-a-function-defined-in-a-class) states that *"the function that you give to map() must be accessible through an import of your module"*; but I still can't get this code to work.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

---

### Add 2

Implementing *Ophion's* suggestion to remove the `calc_kernel` function and simply using:

```
results = pool.map(kernel, torun)
```

works to get rid of the `PicklingError` but now I see that if I create an initial `m_list` of anything more than around 62-63 items I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/gauss_kde_temp.py", line 67, in <module>
    print 'Integral result: ', kde_integration(m_list)
  File "~/gauss_kde_temp.py", line 38, in kde_integration
    pool = Pool(processes=cores)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 232, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 161, in __init__
    self._result_handler.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 494, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
thread.error: can't start new thread
```

Since my actual list in my real implementation of this code can have up to 2000 items, this issue renders the code unusable. Line `38` is this one:

```
pool = Pool(processes=cores)
```

so apparently it has something to do with the number of cores I'm using?

This question ["Can't start a new thread error" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589766/cant-start-a-new-thread-error-in-python) suggests using:

```
threading.active_count()
```

to check the number of threads I have going when I get that error. I checked and it always crashes when it reaches `374` threads. How can I code around this issue?

---

Here's the new question dealing with this last issue: [Thread error: can't start new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602236/thread-error-cant-start-new-thread)

Comment: Running `kernel(sample) < iso` takes the 2 seconds in total, `kernel(sample)` is 99.99% of that time.

Comment: @Ophion yes that's my point. I need to find a way to optimize that process.

Comment: You might want to rephrase it as the `kernel(sample)` process is the most consuming part. Scipy routines are fairly optimized, unless there is some trickery to avoid that call all together there isnt much to be done.

Comment: You mean rephrase the title? I'd be happy to, something like this perhaps? _How to perform an efficient sampling from kernel estimate_

Comment: Perhaps its because I do not use `scipy.stats` much, but to me, at first, it appeared that you were wanting to speed up a `ndarray < x` operation, not calculate `kernel(sample)` faster.

Comment: You could be right. In any case whatever the underlying process might be, I want to make it faster :)

Comment: The kernel density estimate that you're using is implemented in `scipy/stats/kde.py`. It looks like the dominant step is multiplying the inverse covariance by a metric on your data points. You might try reimplementing this method (`evaluate`) in Cython -- though if `np.dot` really is the bottleneck that might not help much. Alternatively, break your data matrix into smaller blocks and call `kernel(block)` on the smaller blocks.

Comment: Actually I just profiled the smaller-block idea and it's much worse. :) Scratch that.

Comment: @lmjohns3 too bad, your first comment sounded promising. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to speed this up is to parallelize `kernel(sample)`:

Taking this code fragment:

```
tik = time.time()
insample = kernel(sample) < iso
print 'filter/sample: ', time.time()-tik
#filter/sample:  1.94065904617
```

Change this to use `multiprocessing`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
tik = time.time()

#Create definition.
def calc_kernel(samp):
    return kernel(samp)

#Choose number of cores and split input array.
cores = 4
torun = np.array_split(sample, cores, axis=1)

#Calculate
pool = Pool(processes=cores)
results = pool.map(calc_kernel, torun)

#Reintegrate and calculate results
insample_mp = np.concatenate(results) < iso

print 'multiprocessing filter/sample: ', time.time()-tik
#multiprocessing filter/sample:  0.496874094009
```

Double check they are returning the same answer:

```
print np.all(insample==insample_mp)
#True
```

A 3.9x improvement on 4 cores. Not sure what you are running this on, but after about 6 processors your input array size is not large enough to get considerably gains. For example using 20 processors its only about 5.8x faster.

Comment: Brilliant! I tried it on my code and I can confirm a ~3.4x improvement on my 4 cores. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone can beat your answer, otherwise I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it works flawlessly with the original code I posted but if you could take a look at the new slightly modified code I edited into the question I'd really appreciate it. I can use your solution perfectly with the original code, but can't get it to work on a more realistic version of my actual code. I'm sorry for not presenting this version from the beginning, I didn't foresee such an issue.

Comment: You should be able to pass `sample` directly to kernel. A simple solution specific to this is remove `calc_kernel` and change `pool.map` to `pool.map(kernel, torun)`. Please let me know if this doesnt work and I will look into it further. I was not aware placing multiprocessing inside a definition had such an effect.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it goes. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I'm stuck now with a threading issue but it's probably best if I just open a new question, otherwise the original question gets buried in new edits. Cheers and thank you very much again mate! Best use of 50 points ever! :)

Answer (score 2):

The claim in the comments section of this article (link below) is

> "SciPy’s gaussian_kde doesn’t use FFT, while there is a statsmodels implementation that does"

…which is a possible cause of the observed poor performance. It goes on to report orders of magnitude improvement using FFT. See @jseabold's reply.

http://slendrmeans.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/will-it-python-machine-learning-for-hackers-chapter-2-part-1-summary-stats-and-density-estimators/

Disclaimer: I have no experience with statsmodels or scipy.