# Using statsmodels.nonparametric.kde instead of scipy.stats.gaussian_kde

Tags: python, scipy, statsmodels

I've read that using the `statsmodels.nonparametric.kde` module instead of [scipy.stats.gaussian_kde](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) can lead to a substantial [speed increase](http://slendrmeans.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/will-it-python-machine-learning-for-hackers-chapter-2-part-1-summary-stats-and-density-estimators/).

I have a simple block of code (4 lines of code) that I currently calculate making use of `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` and I'd like to replace those for its equivalent in `statsmodels` to see if I can actually get an improvement in speed.

This is the MWE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

# Generate random two-dimensional data.
def measure(n):
    m1 = np.random.normal(size=n)
    m2 = np.random.normal(scale=0.5, size=n)
    return m1+m2, m1-m2
m1, m2 = measure(20000)

# Define data limits.
xmin, xmax = m1.min(), m1.max()
ymin, ymax = m2.min(), m2.max()

# Format data correctly.
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])

# Define a certain point value.
x1, y1 = 0.5, 0.5

##############
# Replace with calls to statsmodels.nonparametric.kde from here on.

# 1- Perform a kernel density estimate on the data.
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)

# 2- Get kernel value for the point.
iso = kernel((x1,y1))

# 3- Take a random sample from KDE distribution.
sample = kernel.resample(size=1000)

# 4- Filter the sample to keep only values for which
#    the kernel evaluates to less than what it does in the
#    point (x1,y1). This is the most important step to be replaced.
insample = kernel(sample) < iso
```

As can be seen, it's only 4 lines of code that need replacing. Unfortunately the documentation for `statsmodels.nonparametric.kde` is somewhat poor and I can't figure out how to make such replacements.

The last line is the most important one since it is here that most of the computation time is spent (as stated here [Speed up sampling of kernel estimate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538790/speed-up-sampling-of-kernel-estimate)).

Comment: Unfortunately, statsmodels will not help. The fast fft version in statsmodels is only for univariate KDE (and currently doesn't have a resample method). The multivariate KDE in statsmodels will be slower than scipy's gaussian_kde, I guess.

Comment: If your target is integration, then scipy's gaussian_kde has a `integrate_box` method that might be reasonably fast (in Fortran). But, I never tried.

Comment: Unfortunately `integrate_box` is of no use to me since the integration area is composed of those points which evaluate to less than `kernel(x1,y1)` which is not easily definable.