# How to efficiently apply an operator to the cartesian product of two arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have `a = array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` and `b = array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])`. I want:

```
array([[ -9, -19, -29, -39, -49],
       [ -8, -18, -28, -38, -48],
       [ -7, -17, -27, -37, -47],
       [ -6, -16, -26, -36, -46],
       [ -5, -15, -25, -35, -45]])
```

What's the most efficient way to do this? I have

```
np.transpose([a]) - np.tile(b, (len(a), 1))
```

However I wonder if there's a more efficient way than this if `a` is very large, which wouldn't require copying `b` so much (or vice versa).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some NumPy functions, like `np.subtract`, `np.add`, `np.multiply`, `np.divide`, `np.logical_and`, `np.bitwise_and`, etc. have an "outer" method which can be used to create the equivalent of "multiplication tables":

```
In [76]: np.subtract.outer(a, b)
Out[76]: 
array([[ -9, -19, -29, -39, -49],
       [ -8, -18, -28, -38, -48],
       [ -7, -17, -27, -37, -47],
       [ -6, -16, -26, -36, -46],
       [ -5, -15, -25, -35, -45]])
```

or, using broadcasting:

```
In [96]: a[:, None] - b
Out[96]: 
array([[ -9, -19, -29, -39, -49],
       [ -8, -18, -28, -38, -48],
       [ -7, -17, -27, -37, -47],
       [ -6, -16, -26, -36, -46],
       [ -5, -15, -25, -35, -45]])
```

The performance of the two is about the same:

```
In [98]: a = np.tile(a, 1000)

In [99]: b = np.tile(b, 1000)

In [100]: %timeit a[:, None] - b
10 loops, best of 3: 88.3 ms per loop

In [101]: %timeit np.subtract.outer(a, b)
10 loops, best of 3: 87.8 ms per loop

In [102]: %timeit np.transpose([a]) - np.tile(b, (len(a), 1))
10 loops, best of 3: 120 ms per loop
```

Comment: That second one gives a different result, as you can see

Comment: @unutbu You should add the timing of OP's method for comparison.

Comment: oh looks like `a[:, None]` is the same as `np.transpose([a])`.. so this is the same as mine except I don't have to do the `.tile` explicitly

Comment: @Claudiu: Yes; I think the difference is mainly due to broadcasting.

Comment: @unutbu: Gotcha, makes sense thanks! I asked this question to help me answer [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21839396/15055) - could you perchance take a look and let me know why the non-loop version isn't any faster than the loop version, even after applying the answer from here?

Comment: @Claudiu: To make it an apples-to-apples comparison, we need to make `func` and
`optfunc` return numpy arrays rather than lists. [If you do
that](https://gist.github.com/unutbu/9063262), then the relative timings of the
loop vs non-loop versions becomes on my machine 2.977s vs. 1.959s.
Unfortunately, building a Python list can be far faster than building a NumPy
array. Even though NumPy operations are quicker, you have to
overcome the penalty of instantiating the array(s) before using NumPy pays off.

Comment: @Claudiu: If in optfunc you only loop 1000 times, then optfun (the looping version) is
faster than optfun2 (the vectorized version). However, [if you increase the
number of iterations to say 10000](https://gist.github.com/unutbu/9063494), then optfun2 becomes faster than optfun. 2.339s (looping) vs 0.913s (vectorize).

Comment: @Claudiu: I added an `optfunc3` which is a tiny bit faster than  `optfunc2`. It replaces 5 calls to `np.transpose` with 1 call.

Comment: @unutbu: gotcha, that's what I figured about building the result.  as to `optfunc3`, nice - i figured there was a way to optimize that but didn't put time into figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `np.vstack` for broadcasting but there isn't any new idea in that after other answers:

```
np.vstack(a)-b
```

However I like this one because it is very short.

Furthermore, it also works if `a` and `b` are basic Python lists (unlike the very handy `a[:, None] - b` in a comment above).