# How to kill the thread created by tensorflow.train.SummaryWriter

Tags: multithreading, neural-network, tensorflow

I have a quick question. I noticed that each time tensorflow.train.SummaryWriter is called, a new thread is created. Calling close() method of summarywriter will not kill the thread.

I am wondering if there is a way to kill the threads created by summarywriters?

Thank you for your help!

Best

Comment: Sounds like a potential bug. But these threads are fairly lightweight so it shouldn't affect your performance

Comment: Hi, the issue is when I train a large number of networks at the same time (or one after another), the number of threads will exceed the system capacity and the program will crash, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589766/cant-start-a-new-thread-error-in-python

Comment: Actually are you sure that thread is created by SummaryWriter? Threads are usually created by queue runners and supervisor

Comment: you can stop summary writer thread by calling stop on supervisor -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py#L776

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thank you for your reply. I used treading.active_count() before and after the tf.train.SummaryWriter was called. And the number of threads increased by 1. Would you please give me more details about how to kill the threads by supervisor? I tried but it didn't work. (From the definition I think the stop method only calls the close method of SummaryWriter, which does not work for me for some reason)

Comment: Sorry, that's limit of my knowledge right now -- I would debug it by looking at thread name and trying to figure out where it is created. It seems summarywriter doesn't need its own thread, in the official HowTo, you use  write summaries using .add_summary in main thread

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks. So this can be done on Python API level or we need to check the C++ implementation?

Comment: Python since it's Python threads

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks!